# Symfony FOS User Bundle: Invalid credentials after login / register

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.3

I use Symfony 3.3.14 and the last updated FOS User Bundle. I created a user via /register and after redirecting I'm logged in. If I log out and try to log in again I get the message "Invalid credentials".

If I manually generate a user via terminal in PHP Storm and set a password there, the login is working properly.

So I think the problem is caused by the register, I Think especially on setting the password there.

My security.yml looks like this:

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
                # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

My config.yml:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
```

And my User Entity looks like this:

```
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Whykiki2013
 * Date: 05.11.2017
 * Time: 00:48
 */

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="Sie sind bereits registriert")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $gender;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string" , nullable=true)
     */
    private $street;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string" , nullable=true)
     */
    private $zipcode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $phone;


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getGender()
    {
        return $this->gender;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $gender
     */
    public function setGender($gender)
    {
        $this->gender = $gender;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSurname()
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $surname
     */
    public function setSurname($surname)
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getStreet()
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $street
     */
    public function setStreet($street)
    {
        $this->street = $street;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getZipcode()
    {
        return $this->zipcode;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $zipcode
     */
    public function setZipcode($zipcode)
    {
        $this->zipcode = $zipcode;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $city
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $phone
     */
    public function setPhone($phone)
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        $this->plainPassword = null;
    }




}
```

In basic I followed the steps on setting up FOS UserBundle:

http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html Version 2

I think there is maybe a problem on setting the password with the encoder. But I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Comment: how do you register?  by  using  FOSUB ? Or manually ?

Comment: Hello I registered through the URL /register provided by FOS UserBundle. The User made with registration isn't working. The user made from the terminal is working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm this is quite strange. It seems you have configured it correctly if you did all the steps from documentation, so the problem could be that you really pass invalid credentials.

Do you have fos version ~2.0 in your composer.json? In master branch there were some changes recently that can make problems in symfony 3.3.

Try to also check field enabled in your database.

Btw. You don't need to implement methods eraseCredentials and getSalt. They are already implemented for you in the BaseUser class (name comes from your code).

Comment: Hey I have "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev". 
I supposed to use the wrong pass, but I tested it with Chrome Debugger and he sends the correct value - in my case simple 123456.

Comment: I updated composer yesterday so that I got the changes from the master-Branch from FOS UserBundle.
The email confirmation is not used - the user is activated by default. The DB gets the value 1 for enabled.

If I look in users database table, I can see that the user is flagged with a last login time - so it seems he was logged in. But on frontend I only get the message "Invalid Credentials".

Thank you for your suggestions to clean up my code. This was from a KNP Labs Tutorial - I will delete it.

Comment: That's the thing. You should use `"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0"` without @dev. With @dev you're getting a master version that have some problems in symfony 3. And that's acceptable because it's not stable branch.

Comment: OK, I will delete it also, but if you see my answer before:
It's working now....and I don't know what I changed to make it working.

Comment: Yeah that's why I said that is strange. It could be a cache problem or you simply registered with a wrong password.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what changed.....now it's working with two new generated users via register.

Like said before I deleted the following lines:

```
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function getSalt()
{
    // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
}

public function eraseCredentials()
{
    $this->plainPassword = null;
}
```

They came from a Tutorial where I built my User class before.

The funny thing is: Even if I paste the code lines back in my User-Entity - it's working.

I'm not really satisfied :-) it works but I don't know why...